# Bar chart: How to show y values on top of the every bar(react-native-pure-chart)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

How to display Y-values on top of the bar. Npm
react-native-pure-chart

```
 <PureChart
              height={180}
              defaultColumnWidth={20}
              data={salesData}
              defaultColumnMargin={7}
              type="bar"
              numberOfYAxisGuideLine={5}
              showEvenNumberXaxisLabel={false}

            />
```

Please check Image Here [Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs5iI.jpg)

Comment: what u want don't get it at all, title or the Y values ?

Comment: Y-values (month counts)